# DiscordJSv14 Recording / Receiving Voice Audio

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on a Discord bot using JS and DiscordJSv14, and want the bot to use audio from a voice chat to send to another bot, some type of listen and snitch bot.

So far I got the Bot's connecting to the voice call but can't get any of the packets to send to the other bot.

Here's some code I've got so far:

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: C.id,
    guildId: guild.id,
    adapterCreator: guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    selfDeaf: false,
    selfMute: false,
    group: this.client.user.id,
});

if (isListener) {
    console.log("Listener Is Joining Voice And Listening...");

    const encoder = new OpusEncoder(48000, 2);

    let subscription = connection.receiver.subscribe(ID); // ID = Bot's ID
    // Basically client.user.id

    subscription.on("data", (chunk) => {
        console.log(encoder.decode(chunk));
    });
}
```

Console won't log anything about the chunk
Using DiscordJSv14 + @discordjs/opus

Comment: Not possible with discord api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything worked fine I just needed to add the following code below.

```
this.client = new Client({
      intents: [GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.Guilds],
});
```